# IBM Worklight 6.0 - SAXException when accessing Application Center management console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-portal, websphere-8, worklight-appcenter

I'm currently attempting to get the Worklight Application Center running on a new installation of Worklight v6, running on WebSphere Application Server v8 and WebSphere Portal v8. This appears to be quite simple, and the IBM Installation Manager doesn't complain at all. I can even log in to the Application Center after the install completes. However, the page displays an HTTP 500 error, and "grays out" all options. This also prevents logging out again.

In the WAS logs, the following error occurs exactly when the page errors out:

```
SystemErr     R javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Provider error. Provider: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
SystemErr     R     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createFactory(Persistence.java:175)
SystemErr     R     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:111)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.PureMeapDataJPAImpl.<init>(PureMeapDataJPAImpl.java:211)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.PureMeapDataJPAImpl.fromDataSource(PureMeapDataJPAImpl.java:135)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.DataStoreFactory.getJPADBStore(DataStoreFactory.java:45)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.DataStoreFactory.getDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:33)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.puremeap.util.DataUtil.getData(DataUtil.java:452)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.puremeap.services.BaseService.<init>(BaseService.java:46)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.puremeap.services.MobileServices.<init>(MobileServices.java:51)
SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:56)
SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.common.internal.lifecycle.CreationUtils.createObject(CreationUtils.java:66)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.common.internal.lifecycle.PrototypeObjectFactory.getInstance(PrototypeObjectFactory.java:45)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceInstance.getInstance(ResourceInstance.java:80)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:48)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:34)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:183)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:110)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:52)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1225)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:775)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:457)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:908)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:277)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:166)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1691)
SystemErr     R Caused by: <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.util.GeneralException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: wsjar:file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/PortalServer/wcm/prereq.wcm/wcm/shared/app/ilwwcm-eventlog-jpa.jar!/META-INF/persistence.xml [Location: Line: 3, C: 121]: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.1: Value '2.0' of attribute 'version' of element 'persistence' is not valid with respect to the corresponding attribute use. Attribute 'version' has a fixed value of '1.0'.
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parseNewResource(XMLMetaDataParser.java:379)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:318)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:295)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:268)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation$ConfigurationParser.parse(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:509)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation.parseResources(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:359)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation.load(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:326)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation.load(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:161)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:83)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:117)
SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:59)
SystemErr     R     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createFactory(Persistence.java:171)
SystemErr     R     ... 85 more
```

I have searched for all the combinations of this error that I can think of, with no solutions that actually seem to apply so far. The jar that is triggering the error, "ilwwcm-eventlog-jpa.jar", seems to be a stock library of Portal. In order to troubleshoot, I have even attempted to unpackage the stock JAR, change the referenced xml file to have a "1.0" instead of a "2.0", re-package the JAR, and try that out. This merely causes WAS to throw an exception on a different XML tag in the same file.

Anyone seen this, or have any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Websphere gives to you the wrong version of OpenJPA. The Application Center comes with its own local version of OpenJPA. To eliminate side effects from a global OpenJPA, it is recommended to use the "Parent last" classloader policy:

Enter the Websphere Application Server admin console:

- On the left side: Applications > Application Types > Websphere Enterprise Applications
- From the list of Enterprise Applications, select application center (either AppCenter or AppCenterServices).
- Select "class loading and update detection"
- Class loader order: Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last)

This is usually not the default but you should use this.

- WAR class loader policy: Class loader for each WAR file in application

This should be the default and is good.

- Apply, OK, then if the message about changes appears, click "Save directly to the master configuration".

Just to be sure, restart Websphere Application Server afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Both the AppCenter and AppCenterServices were already set to "(parent last)". Just to be sure, I set them to the other option, restarted WAS, tested, set them back, restarted WAS, and tested again. The same exception is thrown either way.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue.
I figured if I remove the ilwwcm-eventlog-jpa.jar file, it should fix worklight. I changed the extension of the file from .jar to .abc so that the class loader would not find it.
This did fix up WorkLight but instead broke portal's WCM authoring portlet.